# Showing multiple markers on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

My location finder is showing multiple markers, but i don't want that.
I'm not that good with the Google API, so i hope you can help me.

People need to fill in their address, and then he need to show the location. Without showing multiple markers. (only one)

Here is the JS:

```
      var geocoder;
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.132633, 5.291266);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 7,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      }

      function codeAddress() {
        var sAddress = document.getElementById("inputTextAddress").value;
        document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.removeProperty('display');
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(10);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert("Helaas, er is iets fout gegaan. Foutcode: " + status);
            }
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have control of your markers, you need to add them into an array and then remove all of them before adding a new one:

```
  markersArray = []
  function codeAddress() {
    var sAddress = document.getElementById("inputTextAddress").value;
    document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.removeProperty('display');
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(10);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            RemoveMarkers();
            markersArray.push(marker)
        } else {
            alert("Helaas, er is iets fout gegaan. Foutcode: " + status);
        }
      });
  }


  function RemoveMarkers(){
        for(i=0;i<markersArray.length;i++){
             markersArray[i].remove() // I don't remember exactly the name of the gmaps method     
        }
  }
```

I haven't tested the code, but this is the idea you need!

Comment: Thanks @jbartolome for your answer! It's still not working. See here a example: http://bvweijen.nl/23g/web/nogps.php